# Mirai Nikki ending?

Tags: mirai-nikki

Can anyone explain how is it that

> Yuno not only crossed universes, but shattered the wall of space time? It seemed like there would not be another death-game in the 3rd universe since the contestants all lost their will for fighting due to causality breaking down. How is she there? And why is Deus just sitting back letting them universe hop?

I looked into the manga's last chapter sense the anime kind of left it up to imagination in the final scenes but I'm still confused. Below is how the manga describes it:

> [image: manga shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is explained in the OVA/Manga [Mirai Nikki : Redial](http://kotaku.com/the-future-diary-redial-is-the-ending-the-series-was-m-1206240998).
I suggest that you watch/read it.
Short summary:

> As said in the page you posted the memories of 1st Yuno were saved by 1st Murumuru. Later on she gives those to 3rd Yuno.
> While there isn't a survival game in the 3rd world Deus still needs a replacement.
> As 3rd Yuno gains the memories of her other self, she is chosen by Deus as the goddess of the third World.
> Wanting to reunite with 2nd Yukiteru they use Yuno's cell phone from the first world as a link to find him.

Comment: I see, yeah I'll have to look into watching it. I think my usual source should have it.